# hide keyboard in android on input focus without lossing input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, barcode-scanner

I have implemented the barcode scanner using javascript n jquery.
when scanner scans a code we have to add focus on the input text (so that we can read the scanned code).
but it shows the keyboard because of the focus on the input box how can I hide keyboard on scanner machine without losing focus.
i have tried using blur,preventDefault in jquery and with the help of css I tried adding property disable and readonly.
but these didn't worked out.
Anybody is having idea please help me out or let me know any jquery plugin that we can integrate .
I am using php's laravel framework
My barcode scanner scans :-code128

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `we have to add focus on the input text (so that we can read the scanned code)` is quite odd. - There's no need to add focus in order to read something, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems unclear & missing sample code, but to the understanding, **you can try this:**

```css
input[type="text"]{
    color : transparent;
    text-shadow : 0 0 0 #000;
}
input[type="text"]:focus{
    outline : none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="" />
```